# Debug Assertion error for C program

Tags: c++, c, pointers, project

Here's a link to the picture of the error message:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/76298377@N02/6798897020/in/photostream

Here's the actual programming problem. It's Number 3

http://books.google.com/books?id=bSy1hBCLNl8C&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=sales.dat+c%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=mmN9b4WzsN&sig=miAD8-u4ly8K1Mou9ZNHv90Nscc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2wdQT_-4OtSCsgK-l5WyDg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=sales.dat%20c%2B%2B&f=false

and Here's the source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#define numItems     8
#define numSalesP   10

// the product prices 
float prices  [numItems] = {345.0,  853.0, 471.0, 933.0, 721.0, 663.0, 507.0, 259.00};

// the product numbers
int   prodNum [numItems] = {7,      8,     9,     10,    11,    12,    13,    14};

// the salespersons IDs
int   salesP  [numSalesP] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

// the output file pointers
FILE * filePtrs[numSalesP];

// sales totals for every salespersons
float totals  [numSalesP];

//get the product index from the prodNum array
int getProdIndex (int product) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i< numItems; i++) {
        if (prodNum[i] == product) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// get a product price from the product index
float getProdPrice (int prodIndex) {
    return prices[prodIndex];
}

// open a salesperson output file
void openSalesPFiles () {
    int i;
    char fileName[16];;

    for (i=0; i<numSalesP; i++) {
        sprintf(fileName, "salespers%d.dat", i+1);
//DEBUG         cout << fileName << endl;
        filePtrs[i] = fopen(fileName, "r");
    }
}

// close Salespersons files
void closeSalesPFiles () {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<numSalesP; i++) {
        fclose(filePtrs[i]);
    }
}

// get sales person index from its ID
int getSalesPIndex (int salesPerson) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i< numSalesP; i++) {
        if (salesP[i] == salesPerson) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}



int main () {
    int i;                  // generic counter
    FILE * salesFile;       // the input file with all sales
    int salesPId;           // salesperson ID
    int salesPIndex;        // salesperson index in array
    int prodId;             // product ID
    int pIndex;             // product index in array
    int qty;                // quantity
    float total;            // total for one sale

    // open all salespersons output files
    openSalesPFiles();

    // open the input file
    salesFile = fopen("sales.dat", "r");

    // read all record in the input file
    while (!feof(salesFile)) {

        fscanf(salesFile, "%d %d %d", &salesPId, &prodId, &qty);
//DEBUG        cout << salesPId << " --- " << prodId << " --- " << qty << endl;

        // validate sales person
        salesPIndex = getSalesPIndex (salesPId);
        if (salesPIndex < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid Sales person ID " << salesPId << endl;
            continue;
        }

//DEBUG        cout << "Salesperson index : " << salesPIndex << endl;

        // validate product id
        pIndex = getProdIndex (prodId);
        if (pIndex < 0) {
            cout << "invalid product id : " << prodId << endl;
            fprintf(filePtrs[salesPIndex], "Invalid Product ID %d\n", prodId);
            continue;
        } 
        else {
            // compute the sale total
            total = qty * prices[pIndex];
//DEBUG            cout << "total : " << total << endl;;

            // add it to the totals for this salesperson
            totals[salesPIndex] += (qty * prices[pIndex]);

            // write the sale to the salesperson file
            fprintf(filePtrs[salesPIndex], "%d %d %2.2f\n", prodId, qty, total);
        }
    }

    // print totals in salespersons files
    for (i=0; i< numSalesP; i++) {
        fprintf(filePtrs[i], "Total Sales : %8.2f\n", totals[i]);
    }

    // close all files
    closeSalesPFiles();
    fclose(salesFile);


}
```

What is wrong with the code that would make me have such an error? Thanks:S

Comment: Voted To Close as `This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion`. Please try to make your question more suitable for future visitors of the site, and visit the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I agree: but I should add, If that book you are following encourages you to code like that you need a new book, that is C in C++ you are missing the point of the the abstractions afforded to you by C++

Comment: Coding style wise. Why don't you return a few values or have a few more params instead of globals. Theres no reason filePtrs openSalesPFiles cant take in a list of files or return it instead of using it as a global. Also if your allowed use C++11 so you can write `auto varname=func();`

Comment: If you want people to spend effort answering your question, have the courtesy to put some effort in yourself. Don't expect readers to examine a Flickr picture to save you through effort of transcribing the message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assertion comes from a file named *feoferr.c*. That suggests it has something to do with the `feof` function. The assertion says that it expected `stream != NULL`. The assertion failed, so `stream` is evidently a null pointer. Since `feof` takes a file-stream parameter, it's a safe guess that the stream that the assertion message mentions is the file-stream parameter. You call `feof` like this:

```
// open the input file
salesFile = fopen("sales.dat", "r");

// read all record in the input file
while (!feof(salesFile)) {
```

So maybe `salesFile` is a null pointer. As you know, that can happen when `fopen` fails to open the file. Maybe the file doesn't exist, or maybe you don't have read access to it.

---

Next time you encounter an error, use the tools you have in front of you. You have a debugger, and it should interrupt your program when the program fails like this. It can take you to the line that failed, or the line closest to it. That should have given you a hint that the problem was somewhere soon after you called `fopen`. Start investigating there.

Set breakpoints in code later than there, and see whether you get to them before your program fails. If you don't get that far, then don't include those functions when you post a question. Don't bog down potential helpers with lots of irrelevant code to sift through just to get to the real problem.

When you have a problem, make sure your functions return the values you expect them to. If you don't know what to expect them to return, then read the documentation and do some experiments. Make sure you understand all the code you've written.

Comment: What rob said. Callstack is extremely helpful as well. I have exceptions and asserts everywhere in my code and i hardly have unexpected behavior. Just errors that stop the program and bring me to the line telling me what caused the problem